# Image Retification openCV/C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm starting with opencv and image processing in general. I need to make an algorithm, with opencv in `C++`, for image rectification, namely to carry out this transformation in the image:
[image]

I know there are 3 types of `image rectification`:

- `polar`,
- `cylindrical,
- `planar`

The `polar rectification` would meet my needs. But I don't where to start. I know a lot of people here know much about opencv, image processing. What are the basics of and what are the pit falls I should avoid with polar rectification?

Comment: Please put some own trial code in your post. Shows your own effort and researching and prevents your question from being downvoted or deleted.

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) a good start?

Comment: [Marcos Nieto's blog](http://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/) has a lot of good materials on this subject. Specifically, check [this](http://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/source-code-inverse-perspective-mapping-c-opencv/) and [this](http://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/vanishing-point-detection-c-source-code/)